# Magento 2 - Exception when clicking on order

Tags: magento2, error, sales-order

I got this code:

```
namespace UV\Bestellung\Plugin;

class Buttons
{
    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {
        if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){             
            $buttonList->add(
                'bestellschein',
                ['label' => __('Bestellschein'), 'on_click' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl() . '\')',  'class' => 'ship'],
                -1
            );
        }
    }

    public function getUrl() {
        return $this->getUrl('uv_bestellung/order/print/order_id/' . $this->getOrderId());
    }

    public function getOrderId() {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $id = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('sales_order')->getId();
        return $id;
    }
}
```

It adds a button to the order list in adminhtml.

> Sales => Orders

Whenever I click on an order it tries to load it and then a red box appears saying "Exception while loading order".

Anyone knows why that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php

namespace UV\Bestellung\Plugin;

class Buttons
{
    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {
        $orderId = $context->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $backendUrl = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface');

        $printUrl = $backendUrl->getUrl("uv_bestellung/order/createPrint", array('order_id' => $orderId));
        if($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view'){
              $buttonList->add(
                'bestellschein',
                ['label' => __('Bestellschein'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation("'.$printUrl.'")', 'class' => 'generate-order-for-ship'],
                -1
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
namespace UV\Bestellung\Plugin;

class Buttons
{

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /** 
    * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
    */
    protected $backendUrl;

    /**
     * Init plugin
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->backendUrl = $backendUrl;
    }

    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    ) {

        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $request = $context->getRequest();
        if($request->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view') {
            $printUrl = $this->backendUrl->getUrl("uv_bestellung/order/createPrint", array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
            $buttonList->add(
                'bestellschein',
                ['label' => __('Bestellschein'), 'onclick' => 'setLocation("'.$printUrl.'")', 'class' => 'action-default scalable bestellschein'],
                -1
            );
        }   


    }

    /**
     * Retrieve order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
    }
}
```

Create `routes.xml` file under `UV\Bestellung\etc\adminhtml\` and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2018 Magento2. All rights reserved.
 */
-->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="admin">
    <route id="uv_bestellung" frontName="uv_bestellung">
        <module name="UV_Bestellung" before="Magento_Backend"/>
    </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

Create `CreatePrint.php` Controller under `UV\Bestellung\Controller\Adminhtml\Order` and add below code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace UV\Bestellung\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

class CreatePrint extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order
{



    /**
     * Create print order
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $order = $this->_initOrder();
        if ($order) {
            try {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Ths print has been generated.'));
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('The print was not generate for the order.'));
            }
            $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $order->getId()]);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

After run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: can you give me the related routes.xml and controller.php?

Comment: UV\Bestellung\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2018 Magento2. All rights reserved.
 */
-->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="admin">
    <route id="uv_bestellung" frontName="uv_bestellung">
     <module name="UV_Bestellung" before="Magento_Backend"/>
    </route>
  </router>
</config>

Comment: Updates ans pls check and let me know any issue

Comment: I did that and it redirects me to the dashboard :/

Comment: have you run php bin/magento setup:di:compile? Also replace your button url from uv_bestellung/order/print to  uv_bestellung/order/createPrint

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222970/magento-2-onclick-method-executed-before-button-is-clicked#222970 can u explain  in details?

Comment: the problem was solved by this topic here, thanks!

Comment: @L.Klmn Good Enjoy your self

Answer (score 1):

You did the mistake on below code

> $this->_request->getFullActionName()

`$this->_request` variable is an undefined function.

In order **to get request object you should add inject**

`\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` to `__constuct` function

```
protected $_request;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```